# How to make my flexbox elements divide the total height of the container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the elements that are on the left to be distributed across the container's height, taking up 100% of the height in total.

[image]

How can I do it?

Note: "item" is dynamic data

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="d-flex m-0">
      <div class="item">
        item
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex m-0">
      <div class="item">
        item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="d-flex m-0">
      <div class="flex-center">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis libero incidunt rem nisi delectus aliquam maiores hic doloremque aliquid aut! Vitae ex architecto deserunt minima inventore ratione similique ipsa? Facere.
      </div>
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto enim officia itaque, quaerat quisquam deserunt, omnis quae, quas quod maxime at impedit ducimus vel aspernatur. Commodi unde amet itaque alias.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/482yt1df/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex-direction: column`, like so:

```
.left-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d-flex{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  flex: 1;
}
```

If you wish to align items vertically, you can add this:

```
.d-flex {
   ...
   align-items: center;

}
```

[See it on this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fx2ytckp/1/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesnt seem to work correctly, it shows the same result as the inital one.

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot to save the fiddle before copying the link. Updated the link now.

Comment: Yep it works now. Just wanna point out an important thing. Your answer works perfectly but whenever changing the `flex-direction` property you gotta be aware the axis of flexbox rotate which makes several other properties change their behaviour. This isnt a problem at all tho, just something to be aware of when using `flex-direction`

Comment: *whenever changing the flex-direction property* How is your suggested solution different if changing the direction of the items in the the flexbox?

Comment: You can check my answer above, i just used the width (`w-100`), height (`h-50`) and flex (`d-flex align-items-center`) utilites of bootstrap to get the desired result while leaving `flex-direction` untouched.

Comment: Thanks... In my real code I have to use flex-direction :row because I have other elements in the same "line" for that I dont can use flex-direction: column. My items are dynamic I need divide the height on my elements

Comment: @yavg That wasn't in your sample code. Nevertheless, you can have children that has a different flex-direction as the parent (ie, have flexbox within another).

Answer (score 1):

So firstly you need the `no-gutters` class on your row to elimitate gutters between the cols.
Then youll need `h-50` on you flexbox elements inside the col (to get them 50% height each) and youll need `w-100` on the flexbox childs (to make them fill the space). For the vertical centering inside the `item` just add `d-flex align-items-center` classes.

I created a updated version of your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4vep1gy0/

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="d-flex m-0 h-50">
      <div class="item w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
        item
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex m-0 h-50">
      <div class="item w-100 d-flex align-items-center">
        item
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="d-flex m-0">
      <div class="flex-center">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis libero incidunt rem nisi delectus aliquam maiores hic doloremque aliquid aut! Vitae ex architecto deserunt minima inventore ratione similique ipsa? Facere.
      </div>
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto enim officia itaque, quaerat quisquam deserunt, omnis quae, quas quod maxime at impedit ducimus vel aspernatur. Commodi unde amet itaque alias.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To get the vertical centering for the text inside the `item` also add `align-items-center d-flex` classes to it.

Comment: Updated my answer, fiddle and snippet with the vertical centering.

Comment: In my real code I can have n items.. use h-50 in this case can be works... but this is not a good solution with dynamic data

Comment: @yavg in that case you should have a look at the answer of Frank Fajardo below. He's using `flex-direction: column` which will work n items perfectly distributing the avaiable space evenly.